# How to pull a docker image from a github post

Tags: docker

I was following along with an article and I am pretty confused on how to convert this https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter to a docker container or image?? I am pretty confused and the article assumed as if I knew how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the Dockerfile and then run `docker build .` in the directory that you save the Dockerfile to. That will create a Docker image, which you can build a container based off of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two possible ways:

1. Build image locally:

```bash
git clone git@github.com:jpetazzo/nsenter.git
cd nsenter
docker build -t nsenter_image .
docker run --name nsenter_container --rm nsenter_image cat /nsenter > ./nsenter && chmod +x ./nsenter
ls -l nsenter
```

2. Use [docker HUB image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jpetazzo/nsenter/dockerfile):

```bash
mkdir nsenter
cd nsenter
docker run --name nsenter_container --rm jpetazzo/nsenter cat /nsenter > ./nsenter && chmod +x ./nsenter
ls -l nsenter
```